# Assign query result to variable and use it in python script

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I want to assign datadir path from a SQL query to variable and use it:

My attempt:

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(hostaddress,user,password,db_name)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@datadir")
    getsql = cursor.fetchall
    os.rename(getsql + database, '/tmp/backup/DATABASES/' + database)
    db.close()
except Exception as err:
        logging.error(str(err))
```

Error, after executing

> ERROR:mysql:unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'str'

Where do I have an error? Please help. I don't understand my error

Comment: `getsql = cursor.fetchall` is a method, so `getsql = cursor.fetchall()` with the `()` might fix the immediate error to call the actual method. But it's going to return a tuple (and possibly within a list).

Comment: In `getsql + database`, what is `database`?

Comment: "database" it is an argument of fucntion of deleting of database

Comment: cursor.fetchall(), yes i forgot about it. but it does not help

Comment: So what did it return? A list with a tuple inside, as I said? You can't pass that to `os.rename` so you need to index it to get the info you want.

Comment: i should get element of tuple ? right ?

Comment: you will get tuple of tuple, with one element in your case.

Comment: but, how can i get result of query and add to os.rename it ?

Comment: please remove postgres from tags